# Display background image in Neo4j browser

Tags: neo4j

Some nodes in my graph database have a property which contain a URL to an image. I wanted to use Neo4j browser's style sheet functionality to display that image as the background image of a node.
My .grass file looks like this:

```
node {
  diameter: 40px;
  color: #DFE1E3;
  border-color: #D4D6D7;
  border-width: 2px;
  text-color-internal: #000000;
  caption: '{name}';
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: #00aaee;
}

node.Actor {
  color: #AD62CE;
  border-color: #9453B1;
  text-color-internal: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: url('{image}');
}
```

After I uploaded the file, the line `background-image: url('{image}');` gets converted to `background-image: url({image});` (missing apostrophes). No image is shown in the browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything wrong.

The feature is not supported in the Neo4j browser. Other visualization solutions do exist. Unfortunately the ones that use this feature out of the box are not open source and may require a commercial license.

Of these solutions are:

- http://linkurio.us/
- https://www.tomsawyer.com/products/visualization/index.php
- http://www.keylines.com/

Comment: So the better way would be to use a Javascript library like D3.js and implement it myself?

Comment: Yes, and if you do, please share it with us via Twitter @neo4j, we'd love to share it back to the community if you're willing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @Kenny Bastani said most of the libraries that implement this feature have a commercial license.

For a full list of the supported ones have a look to [the official Neo4J visualize page](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/visualize).